# Checking if HTML element exists with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to check if an element exists on an HTML page with Selenium/Python.

This is my function:

```
class runSelenium(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # define a class attribute
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def isElementPresent(self, locator):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print ('No such thing')
            return False
        return True

    def selenium(self):
        self.driver.get("https://somepage.com")
        isElement = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='item'][6]")
        isElement1 = str(isElement)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        run = runSelenium()
        run.selenium()
```

I am trying to pick the result with a Boolean value but with no luck:

```
isElement = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='item'][6]")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The function itself looks good, could you elaborate more about what your problem is? Thanks.

Comment: When i check the isElement variable, it doesn't show me whether it's True or False

Comment: Could you show how are you using the `isElement` variable after? Thanks.

Comment: I try to check it as a Bool and as a String and for both I see 'error, not defined' under the watch in Visual Studio:


        isElement = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='badgeList__item'][6]")

        isElement1 = str(isElement)

Comment: Could you please post the complete code you have so far, just to see the bigger picture?

Comment: Sure, give me a min. Ok, added

Answer (score 5):

You need to un-indent the last code block:

```
class runSelenium(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # define a class attribute
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def isElementPresent(self, locator):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print ('No such thing')
            return False
        return True

    def selenium(self):
        self.driver.get("https://somepage.com")
        isElement = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='item'][6]")
        isElement1 = str(isElement)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = runSelenium()
    run.selenium()
```

Answer (score -2):

So I restarted the IDE (Visual Studio 2013) and it works now fine.. The code is correct 100%

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing here?